# setProperty on a Properties object not writing changes to a .properties file in Android with Java

Tags: java, android, assets

I am trying to change values in a .properties file located in the assets folder of my Android project. I do not get any exceptions thrown or errors in the App and no changes are made to the file. I am running Android Studio as my IDE.

```
try {
     Properties props = new Properties();
     AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
     InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("User.properties");
     props.load(inputStream);
     props.setProperty("id", value);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did you output the file back to your drive via output stream?

Comment: Well no, you're not *saving* the properties afterwards. When you call `load`, that doesn't mean "Make the `Properties` object permanently associated with the file" - it just loads the contents of the file...

Comment: No I have not, to .store() this I would need an OutPutStream, problem is I am still new and learning about this. if one of you could help me please.

Comment: It also came to my attention that you can not write to the Assets folder in Android?